# How to apply default CSS styling to all HTML pages

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I literally just started learning HTML and I'm making a basic website in Dreamweaver. I would like to know how I can create a default CSS style sheet so it can apply to all web pages. At present I need to make the stylesheet changes to all pages which is troublesome. Would appreciate some references/tutorials on how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a css directory in your websites root (where your index.html page usually is) and adding a css file called style.css.

You will then need to link each of your pages to your newly created stylesheet (style.css) in your  section:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' type='text/css' media='screen' charset='utf-8'>
```

This tells each of your webpages to look for a stylesheet (rel='stylesheet') at the location defined by 'href' (href='css/style.css'), this is assuming that all your files are in the same directory, if not; you'll have to point them to the appropriate place relative to their current location.

For example if you have a folder of 'trips' containing several files 'index.html, map.html' or whichever, they would have to point to "href='../css/style.css'.

Comment: Thanks. I started doing some research into external/internal stylesheets (wasnt aware of the technical term) and it seems pretty easy :D.

Comment: Ah I just remembered (sorry, been a while since I wrote html from scratch with css, but as well as relational references, you can also do static references by doing /css/style.css (note the forward slash at the beginning, which can make things easier than risking having no stylesheet by writing the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="class.css" />
```

This is probably the best way to include a .css file into your page. However, as far as I know, you have to do it on every page. Please someone clear this for me if you know better :).

Obviously it does mean href="[path to .css file]" if your files are in another place.

Hope this helps,

Ross.